# How to perform Taylor series expansion consisting of cell averaged derivatives in a computational element?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, interpolation, discontinuous-galerkin

I have encountered the term cell "**Cell averaged derivatives**" and **"Taylor series expansion using cell averaged derivatives about centroid**" in the context of polynomial representation in any cell (computational element with some higher order interpolation polynomial nodes).

Here is the link to the below paper:
http://dept.ku.edu/~cfdku/papers/AIAA-2009-605.pdf

[image]

I have also read the reference of this reference paper 
http://people.math.gatech.edu/~yingjie/publications/centr_DG_ovlpcell_new_iii.pdf
*Section 4.1*

I tried to find alternate references and easier sources of explanation, but everywhere it has been mentioned that the coefficients of the above Taylor series expansion can be found easily.

However, I am still unable to grasp the procedure properly. It would be nice if someone could help me understand which seems to be trivial for everyone.